# Passing a php string value containing single codes to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know though this question have been asked many times but none of the solutions seems working for me. I am new to JS so need help badly

I have a string value in php that contains value from Database i.e

```
$row['Product_name'] // Contains value --> Oxford Club Men's Solid Casual Shirt
```

I want to pass this value in addToCart() JavaScript function on a button click,
May be something like onclick="addToCart()" and passing $row['Product_name']; as its argument

But this gives me an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I even tried using json but same problem can Someone give a better solution to this

```
 <?php foreach ($popularProducts as $row) {

                    $data = array(
                        'id' => $row["product_id"],
                        'name' => $row["product_name"],
                        'image' => '1.jpg',
                        'price' => $row["product_selling_price"],
                        'discount' => 0,
                        'qty' => 1
                        );
  ?>

 <div class="ratings">
     <p class="pull-right items">
        <a onclick='addToCart(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>)' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Add to cart">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 
         </a>
      </p>
</div>
<?php
    }

 ?>
```

and the function

```
function addToCart(var jsonArray){
     alert(jsonArray);
 }
```

on click it gives an error

Comment: add your code here if you've tried

Comment: It does help if you supply at least a sample of the code so we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: I did provide the sample code !!

Comment: You are missing quotes around the `<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>`.

Comment: Within the function ? @PietervandenHam

Comment: Your code will output `addToCart(Product name)`, which is syntactically incorrect. It should be `addToCart("Product name")`.

Answer (score 0):

first if you use jquery you can pass product name as data. [Read This](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
   <button id="prod" data-name="<?php echo $row['Product_name']; ?>">AAA</button>
```

then use click function to retrieve that data as follows:

```
$('#prod').click(function(){
    var n = $(this).data('name');
  console.log(n);
});
```

Here is a working demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldprumgy/1/).

You can even store the whole array/object as json:

`<button class="prod" data-product="<?php echo json_encode($row); ?>">AAA</button>`

And retrieve as:

```
$('.prod').click(function(){
    var obj = $.parseJSON($(this).data('product'));
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(obj.name); //access all your db_columns as properties
});
```

Comment: I don't want only name but other data as well. Its creating problem with name only

Comment: You can send other as well just follow that format. If you store something as `data-something` then you need to fetch it as `$(this).data('something')` . You can replace `something` with whatever you want.

Comment: @coderbca  I've edited my answer. I guess this should be ok for you now.

Comment: Even this isn't working :( I have 4 buttons and i want this want depending upon which one is clicked

Comment: @coderbca then my first solution should be ok. you just have to rewrite 1st solution. and i guess you know id should be unique. so for 1st solution you just have to create 4 button with 4 unique id store data based on your button. then write click functions based on their id.

Comment: I cant write click function for all the buttons as the buttons are dynamic and they wary based on the data from the database. Now What should I be doing ?

Comment: @coderbca then remove the id field just assign a class to the button. It can be same to all buttons. check the 2nd part of edited answer. and now it'll work with this single function :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass information between PHP and Javascript, you will want to echo the PHP variables to the HTML document.

Example:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="addToCart('<?= $row['Product name'] ?>')" />
```

Which will result in this being echoed to the HTML document:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="addToCart('Some fancy product')" />
```

Of course echoing PHP variables is not limited to just echoing them in "onclick" attributes. You could echo them in a `<script>` tag as well, if you would want that.

```
<script>var thisItem = "<?= $ItemName ?>";</script>
```

Note: when doing this, make sure to escape your variables properly.

Comment: It still throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error

Comment: Make sure to put quotes around the echoed string: `"<?= $variable ?>"`  instead of just plain `<?= $variable ?>`